# Save uploaded file - using

Tags: c#, asp.net, using-statement

I've uploaded a file with the FileUpload control. I've got the path and everything and I would like to save the image to the server. I don't want to use the SaveAs() method.
I wonder, is there a way to save the file with using-statement?

Comment: Please try to elaborate more on why do you want to do so

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx. You should be able to stream the data into a new file created in permanent storage. Or just do a copy operation from the tmp path you said you already have.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use StreamReader to read the file from file upload and use StreamWriter class to write  it to your server with Server.MapPath() function(ur server absolute path)

Answer (score 0):

You have [FileUpload.FileBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) method which returns array of bytes of uploaded file or use `FileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream` property to get stream of uploaded file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string pilepath = Server.MapPath(".") +"\\"+ fl.FileName;
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(pilepath, fl.FileBytes);
```

fl.FileBytes
Gets an array of the bytes in a file that is specified by using a FileUpload control.